# Validate in mongoose without saving

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to run the mongoose validator without also saving? Basically, wanting to do a dry run of a change and making sure that it *would* save if I chose to:

```js
myThing.validated_property = 5;
try { myThing.check(); } catch(e) { console.log("nope!") }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call [`validate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate) on a Mongoose doc to evaluate its validation rules:

```js
myThing.validated_property = 5;
myThing.validate(function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log('nope!') }       
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer. I tried as you suggested, but it is giving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: myThing.validate is not a function