# Mongoose validate Schema with no Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to validate some inner elements of an object against schemas that are members of a larger schema before posting that object on the model correspondent to that larger schema.

Someone already asked this question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35110097/3128369) has something similar on the second option proposed:

```
var p = new People({
    name: 'you',
    age: 3
});

p.validate(function(err) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log('pass validate');
});
```

The problem is that before doing the validation one has to create a new model with `var People = mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema);`.

Does this mean in this case that a new collection `'People'` will be stored in the MongoDB database?

Is the act of calling  `mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema);` altering the database in any way?

If so, is there a way to do this validation without creating a new collection, in this case `'People'`?

The schema I want to validate will be stored as a component of another document already in the database and I don't want to pollute the database with unused collections.

Comment: it won't be stored in batabase until you write it into database

Comment: Thanks @monkeyinsight . The element won't be stored, but, is calling mongoose.model('People', peopleSchema); creating a new collection in the database?

Comment: mongoose auto creates _collection_ on startup only if it has indexes. New _document_ is added to mongodb collection, only when you call `model.create()` or `document.save()`.