# Validate child schema using built-in validators without creating a model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a use case where `ParentSchema` contains an array of entries which can take on multiple different schemas. Each entry has a `category` field that indicates the intended schema for each entry. My goal is to validate each entry based on the given `category` leveraging Mongoose's built-in validator.

How can I do this without creating a model for the schema with which I am trying to validate? One way I can think of is to create a custom validator that checks for all the required fields and so on, but it would be super convenient if I could just use the built-in validator that comes with the Schema.

[Here is a related question with no answers...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647954/mongoose-validate-schema-with-no-model)

```js
const parentSchema = new Schema({
  entries: [childSchema]
});

const categorySchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["A", "B"]
  },
  name: String
});

// A bunch of required fields and enums are defined in these schema
// I would like to use these schema definitions to validate input objects without creating models
const typeADataSchema = new Schema({});
const typeBDataSchema = new Schema({});

const childSchema = new Schema({
  category: categorySchema,
  data: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    enum: [typeADataSchema, typeBDataSchema]
    validate: [
      {
        validator: function (value) {
          if (this.category.code === "A") {
            // Need help with this exemplary `validate` method
            return typeADataSchema.validate(value)
          } else if (this.category.code === "B") {
            return typeBDataSchema.validate(value)
          } else {
            return false;
          }
       }
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using [discriminators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)!

```js
const dataSchema = new Schema({}, {discriminatorKey: "type", _id: false});

const childSchema = new Schema({
  data: dataSchema
});

const typeADataSchema = new Schema({});
const typeBDataSchema = new Schema({});

childSchema.path("data").discriminator("A", typeADataSchema);
childSchema.path("data").discriminator("B", typeBDataSchema);

const parentSchema = new Schema({
  entries: [childSchema]
});
```